# Getting length of a float array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, graphics, vtk, sizeof

Im trying to find out the length of a given X array in my c++ program and I can't figure out how to see how many elements are in there.

```
float *X = (float *) rgrid->GetXcoordinates->GetVoidPointer(0);
```

The array is declared there and from the data set we're given these are the X coordinates

X_COORDINATES 50 float
-10 -9.59184 -9.18367 -8.77551 -8.36735 -7.95918 -7.55102 -7.14286 -6.73469
-6.32653 -5.91837 -5.5102 -5.10204 -4.69388 -4.28571 -3.87755 -3.46939 -3.06122
-2.65306 -2.2449 -1.83673 -1.42857 -1.02041 -0.612245 -0.204082 0.204082 0.612245
1.02041 1.42857 1.83673 2.2449 2.65306 3.06122 3.46939 3.87755 4.28571
4.69388 5.10204 5.5102 5.91837 6.32653 6.73469 7.14286 7.55102 7.95918
8.36735 8.77551 9.18367 9.59184 10

So I know that there are 49 elements in the array but I don't want to just hardcore that into my code like X[49] but I just want to be able to grab the length then -1 to grab that number instead.

I've seen solutions for sizeof but when I try to print out

```
cout << "X length is" << sizeof(X) << endl;
```

I just get 8 and if I try

```
cout <<"X length is" << sizeof(X) / sizeof(X[0]) << endl;
```

I just get 2, so I was wondering if there was a way in C++ to get the length that I want (in this case 50) and be able to iterate it from there?

Comment: Simply put, you can't do what you want to do. `sizeof(X)` is simply the size of the pointer. You should consider using a `std::vector<float>` instead.

Comment: Sorry im new to c++ but are you saying that to find the length I should use std::vector<float> somehow or thats how I should declare my X array?

Comment: You don't have a pointer to an array of `float`s. You have a pointer to the first `float` in the array. Whether or not there are more `float`s after the first is unknown to the pointer. A pointer only knows where something is, not how many. `std::vector<float>` is a smarter container of `float`s. It knows where they are and how many there are. It can grow or shrink as you add or remove more `float`s. Probably the handiest tool in C++.

Comment: Ah I see unfortunately this is part of a homework assignment so I can't change the float *X = (float *) rgrid->GetXcoordinates->GetVoidPointer(0); line so I guess im stuck on using X[49]

Comment: Since `GetVoidPointer()` just returns a pointer to the start of the array, unless there is another method provided to determine the length of the array (ie, `rgrid->GetXcoordinates->GetArrayLength(0);`), there is simply no way to get it from just the pointer itself.

Comment: Ugggh, why is the homework, "learn bad c++ practices that will take you ages to unlearn". Talk to your teach and ask why you are not allowed to use a vector.

Comment: If rgrid is a VTK Rectilinear Grid, you should be able to call rgrid->GetDimensions().  That will give you the X, Y, and Z dimensions of the grid.

Comment: Oh shoot thanks @DaveChen ! I didn't realize that but that would totally work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
auto sz_x = sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x);
```

the number of elements in the array = the size of the entire array in bytes / the size of an element from the array in bytes